# Pandas - pivoting multiple columns into fewer columns with some level of detail kept

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Say I have the following code that generates a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"customer_code": ['1234','3411','9303'],
                   "main_purchases": [3,10,5],
                   "main_revenue": [103.5,401.5,99.0],
                   "secondary_purchases": [1,2,4],
                   "secondary_revenue": [43.1,77.5,104.6]
                  })

df.head()
```

[image: img]

There's the `customer_code` column that's the unique ID for each client.

And then there are 2 columns to indicate the purchases that took place and revenue generated from main branches by those clients.

And another 2 columns to indicate the purchases/revenue from secondary branches by those clients.

I want to get the data into a format like this, where a pivot is done where there's a new column to differentiate between main vs secondary, but the revenue numbers and purchase columns are not mixed up:

[image: img2]

The obvious solution is just to split this into 2 dataframes, and then simply do a concatenate, but I'm wondering whether there's a built-in way to do this in a line or two - this strikes me as the kind of thing someone might have thought to bake in a solution for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little column renaming to get the "revenue" and "purchases" in the column names first using a regular expression and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) we can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) to convert these now stubnames from columns to rows:

```
# Reorder column names so stubnames are first
df.columns = [df.columns[0],
              *df.columns[1:].str.replace(r'(.*)_(.*)', r'\2_\1', regex=True)]

# Convert wide_to_long
df = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        df,
        i='customer_code',
        stubnames=['purchases', 'revenue'],
        j='type',
        sep='_',
        suffix='.*'
    )
        .sort_index()  # Optional sort to match expected output
        .reset_index()  # retrieve customer_code from the index
)
```

`df`:

|  | customer_code | type | purchases | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1234 | main | 3 | 103.5 |
| 1 | 1234 | secondary | 1 | 43.1 |
| 2 | 3411 | main | 10 | 401.5 |
| 3 | 3411 | secondary | 2 | 77.5 |
| 4 | 9303 | main | 5 | 99 |
| 5 | 9303 | secondary | 4 | 104.6 |

---

What does reordering the column headers do?

```
df.columns = [df.columns[0],
              *df.columns[1:].str.replace(r'(.*)_(.*)', r'\2_\1', regex=True)]
```

Produces:

```
Index(['customer_code', 'purchases_main', 'revenue_main',
       'purchases_secondary', 'revenue_secondary'],
      dtype='object')
```

The "type" column is now the suffix of the column header which allows `wide_to_long` to process the table as expected.

Comment: a possibly simpler option (my regex is horrible)  for reshaping the columns: ``df.columns[[0]].append(df.columns[1:].str.split("_").str[::-1].str.join("_"))``

Answer (score 1):

You can abstract the reshaping process with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/); they are just a bunch of wrapper functions in Pandas:

```
#pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.pivot_longer(index = 'customer_code',
                names_to=('type', '.value'), 
                names_sep='_', 
                sort_by_appearance=True)
 
  customer_code       type  purchases  revenue
0          1234       main          3    103.5
1          1234  secondary          1     43.1
2          3411       main         10    401.5
3          3411  secondary          2     77.5
4          9303       main          5     99.0
5          9303  secondary          4    104.6
```

The `.value` in `names_to` signifies to the function that you want that part of the column to remain as a header; the other part goes under the `type` column. The split is determined in this case by `names_sep` (there is a `names_pattern` option, that allows regular expression split); if you do not care about the order of appearance, you can set `sort_by_appearance` as False.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use melt() and concat() function to solve this problem.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = df.melt(
          id_vars='customer_code',
          value_vars=['main_purchases', 'secondary_purchases'],
          var_name='type',
          value_name='purchases',
          ignore_index=True)

df2 = df.melt(
          id_vars='customer_code',
          value_vars=['main_revenue', 'secondary_revenue'],
          var_name='type',
          value_name='revenue',
          ignore_index=True)
```

Then we use concat() with the parameter axis=1 to join side by side and use sort_values(by='customer_code') to sort data by customer.

```
result= pd.concat([df1,df2['revenue']], 
               axis=1,
               ignore_index=False).sort_values(by='customer_code')
```

Using replace() with regex to align type names:

```
result.type.replace(r'_.*$','', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

The above code will output the below dataframe:

|  | customer_code | type | purchases | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1234 | main | 3 | 103.5 |
| 3 | 1234 | secondary | 1 | 43.1 |
| 1 | 3411 | main | 10 | 401.5 |
| 4 | 3411 | secondary | 2 | 77.5 |
| 2 | 9303 | main | 5 | 99 |
| 5 | 9303 | secondary | 4 | 104.6 |